# Declaring dependencies only used for type checking in Python

Tags: python, setuptools, typing, pyproject.toml

I often have packages which might be used with my library, but which I don't use any functionality from. However I also want to register all of this with the type system.

For example let's say that my package `a` has a function that can accept `b.B`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING;
    from b import B

def do_a(b: B):
    pass
```

This works well at runtime and also for type checking, but it's not clear how `b` should be treated in the package metadata. Is it a dependency that should go into `dependencies` in `pyproject.toml` because it's being imported (albeit conditionally) in the project? Automated tools like https://github.com/tweag/FawltyDeps will flag this package if it's not declared at all. Should it be declared as an optional extra? Or not declared at all?

Comment: Hm. If you can receive a `b.B` somewhere, I can imagine two options. First - transitive dependency: you need an annotation from some lower-level package, but do not use its exported functionality. This means you already depend on `b`, so why not just declare it as an explicit dependency? Another option is "user can also use my package with `b`, but is not required to do so". In this case you have a peer dependency, I'd probably add it as "extra" - it shouldn't harm and makes your intent explicit.